# Ошибка сборки пустого кода

Tags: gcc, c

При сборке кода пример.сс

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

командой

```
$ gcc -o пример пример.cc && ./пример
```

выводится ошибка

*undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'*

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно так:

```
$ g++ -o пример пример.cc && ./пример
```

Answer (score 7):

Или переименовать файл в `пример.c`. Напоминаю:

1. C-файлы по умолчанию имеют расширение `.c`.
2. C++-файлы по умолчанию имеют расширение `.cc`, `.cp`, `.cxx`, `.cpp`, `.c++`, `.C`.

Варианты таких извращений, как компиляция GCC, а затем линковка G++, опустим.
Еще способ - использование ключа `-x` компилятора, который задает используемый язык.

Comment: .c и .C это одно и то же по-моему.

Comment: > .c и .C это одно и то же по-моему.

сам натыкался на C++ код именно с таким расширением. (в unix регистр имён файлов имеет значение)

Comment: The Definitive Guide to GCC Уильяма фон Хагена говорит следующее (перевод мой):  

> Компиляторы GCC оценивают суффиксы имен файлов для определения типа используемого компилятора. Таблица 2-1 перечисляет суффиксы, имеющие отношение к g++.  
>
> Таблица 2-1 Суффиксы имен файлов C++  
> .C - обрабатываемый препроцессором код C++  
> .cc - обрабатываемый препроцессором код C++ (это стандартное расширение для файлов исходного кода на языке C++)  
> .cpp - обрабатываемый препроцессором код C++  
> .cxx - обрабатываемый препроцессором код C++  
> .ii - не обрабатываемый препроцессором код C++